# make full height div in html and css

Tags: html, css

I want make divs like first photo:
[image]
but when I use 100% for height of yellow and blue divs
they came out of screen like second photo:
[image]
what should I do?

Comment: Can you post your css/html?  It looks like you're using some padding or margin to push everything down 60px.  By doing this, the remaining height of the screen that you need to fill is no longer 100%.

Comment: When u use percentage values u have to make sure the wrapping div has non percentage values in order for it to work. Also please include ur HTML and CSS code.

Comment: short answer: you can always use the css calc function, like header you can use ( width:calc(100%-60px); and so

Comment: And 1 more thing, you can use the position fixed for top header and make it full width with padding from sides to put the logo in a new layer with higher z-index ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just wanted to address the hight issue you could use `vh` combined with `calc`.

```
.header {
   height: 60px;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh -60px);
}
```

this would fill the height of the page minus 60px.

Heres an example;
https://jsfiddle.net/0ndbw3to/

Comment: What if `.header` grows taller than `60px`? Also, what about `logo box` and `menu box`?

Comment: yeah totally @AndyHoffman if that was the case then it would need to be updated.

Answer (score 4):

- Set the `flex` parent (`body` in this case) to `min-height: 100vh` and set its direction to `column` so children stack
- Set the body of the page (`main`) to `flex-grow: 1` so it takes up all available space, but *not more* than what's available
- Create a few nested `flexbox`es using the default `row` direction
- Push nested contents to the right using `justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
body, html { margin: 0 }

body, header, main {
  display: flex;
}

header, main {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.logo, .menu-box {
  flex-basis: 60px;
}

body {
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #ccc;  
}

.logo {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: lightgreen;  
}

.menu-box {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</header>
<main>
  <aside class="menu-box"></aside>
</main>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fc2yj1dw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

A *simple* solution using [`CSS Grid layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)(for current support see [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)):

1. Set the layout height as 100vh.
2. `grid-template-columns: 1fr 60px`: sets the columns - the *logo* and *menu box* at 60px and the *header* and *content* take the *remaining space* horizontally.
3. `grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr`: set the rows - the *header* and the *logo* at 60px and the *content* and the *menu box* take the *remaining space* vertically.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* remove the default browser margin */
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 60px; /* set the columns */
  grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr; /* set the rows */
  height: 100vh; /* set the height of the layout */
}

/* presentation styles */
.wrapper>*{border:1px solid}.header{background:#00f}.logo{background:orange}.content{background:#f0f8ff}.aside{background:grey}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="aside"></div>
</div>
```